# which is the most efficient way to remove DataFrame rows based on a condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a non-optimal solution to a problem and I'm searching for a better one.

My data looks like this:

````
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'score', 'duration', 'user'],
                  data=[[1, 800, 60, 'abc'], [1, 900, 60, 'zxc'], [2, 800, 250, 'abc'], [2, 5000, 250, 'bvc'],
                        [3, 6000, 250, 'zxc'], [3, 8000, 250, 'klp'], [4, 1400, 500,'kod'],
                        [4, 8000, 500, 'bvc']])```
````

As you can see instances are pairs of identical ids with the same duration and different scores. My goal is to remove all id pairs that have a duration of less than 120 or where at least one user has a score less than 1500.

So far my solution is like this:

```
# remove instances with duration > 120 (duration is the same for every instance of the same id)
df= df[df['duration'] > 120]

# groupby id and get the min value of score
test= df.groupby('id')['score'].min().reset_index()

# then I can get a list of the id's where at least one user has a score below 1500 and remove both instances with the same id

for x in list(test[test['score'] < 1500]['id']):
    df.drop(df.loc[df['id']==x].index, inplace=True)
```

However, the last bit is not very efficient and quite slow. I have around 700k instances in df and was wondering what is the most efficient way to remove all instances with id equal to the ones found in list(test[test['score'] < 1500]['id']). Also a note, for simplicity i used an integer for id in this example but my id's are objects that have this kind of format 4240c195g794530fj4e10z53.

However, you're welcome to show me a better initial approach to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create the condition , then groupby on the boolean column based on the id column and then transform with `all` to retain groups that satisfies the condition for all the rows in the group.

```
#retain duration greater than or equal to (ge) 120 and id that has score ge 1500
cond = df['duration'].ge(120) & df['score'].ge(1500)
out = df[cond.groupby(df['id']).transform('all')]
```

Or chaining them up in 1 line:

```
out = df[(df['duration'].ge(120) & df['score'].ge(1500))
                    .groupby(df['id']).transform('all')]
```

---

```
   id  score  duration user
4   3   6000       250  zxc
5   3   8000       250  klp
```

Comment: Thanks - that's a neat solution, haven't used .transform('all') before. However, I noticed an inconsistency in my df. For some reason some id's are single (so 1 instance per id instead of 2) and I want to get rid of them. If it's no bother, could you advise me of an appropriate way to do that?

Comment: @idontknowmuch try this `cond = df['id'].duplicated(keep=False) & df['duration'].ge(120) & df['score'].ge(1500)` and then `out = df[cond.groupby(df['id']).transform('all')]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Making a loop to process `pandas` `dataframe` or `numpy` is almost always a bad idea with regards to performance.
You need to use `pandas` or `numpy` methods, except the `apply` method which is not so performant.

I am adding anky's response and add two other slightly less performant solutions.

```py
def with_isin(df):
    df= df[df['duration'] > 120]
    test= df.groupby('id')['score'].min()<1500
    return df.isin(test[test].index)

def with_join(df):
    df= df[df['duration'] > 120]
    test= df.groupby('id')['score'].min()<1500
    return df[df.join(test,rsuffix='_test', on='id')['score_test']]

def anky(df):
    return df[(df['duration'].ge(120) & df['score'].ge(1500))
                    .groupby(df['id']).transform('all')]

%timeit with_isin(df)
#>>> 1.22 ms ± 18.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit with_join(df)
#>>> 2.23 ms ± 48.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%timeit anky(df)
#>>> 1.15 ms ± 42.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```